# rearrange dataframe based on day and month from another dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

df_a

```
datetime      var
2016-10-15    110.232790
2016-10-16    111.020661
2016-10-17    112.193496
2016-10-18    113.638143
2016-10-19    115.241448
```

and df_b

```
datetime      var
2000-01-01    165.792185
2000-01-02    166.066959
2000-01-03    166.411669
2000-01-04    167.816046
2000-01-05    169.777814
2000-10-15    114.232790
2000-10-16    113.020661
```

df_a has information for the year 2016 and df_b has information for years from 2000 to 2015 (there is no overlap in the years).

Can I arrange the df_b dataframe to have the same order in terms of day of year as df_a?

Comment: Are datetimes indices in both DataFrames?

Comment: @jezrael yes they are

Comment: Super, so solution is OK ;)

Comment: @jezrael, thanks for the soln! it is great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) and [`month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html) & 
[`day`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.day.html) or [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) with [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetmeIndex.strftime.html):

*Notice: `datetime`s are indices in both DataFrames*

```
df = df_b[df_b.index.month.isin(df_a.index.month) & df_b.index.day.isin(df_a.index.day)]
print (df)
                   var
datetime              
2000-10-15  114.232790
2000-10-16  113.020661
```

Or:

```
df = df_b[np.in1d(df_b.index.strftime('%m%d'), df_a.index.strftime('%m%d'))]
print (df)
                   var
datetime              
2000-10-15  114.232790
2000-10-16  113.020661
```

Comment: plz also look at related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47627965/rearrange-groups-in-dataframe-based-on-day-and-month-from-another-dataframe-inde