# rearrange groups in dataframe based on day and month from another dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

df_a

```
datetime      var
2016-10-15    110.232790
2016-10-16    111.020661
2016-10-17    112.193496
2016-10-18    113.638143
2016-10-19    115.241448
2017-01-01    113.638143
2017-01-02    115.241448
```

and df_b

```
datetime      var
2000-01-01    165.792185
2000-01-02    166.066959
2000-01-03    166.411669
2000-01-04    167.816046
2000-01-05    169.777814
2000-10-15    114.232790
2000-10-16    113.020661
2001-01-01    164.792185
2001-01-02    161.066959
2001-01-03    156.411669
2002-01-04    167.816046
2002-01-05    169.777814
2002-10-15    174.232790
2003-10-16    114.020661
```

df_a has information for the year 2016, 2017 and df_b has information for years from 2000 to 2015 (there is no overlap in the years).

Can I arrange each group in the df_b dataframe to have the same order in terms of day of year as df_a? A group is defined as rows with the same year e.g. 2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain new condition for check [`year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html):

```
df = df_b[df_b.index.month.isin(df_a.index.month) &
          df_b.index.day.isin(df_a.index.day) & 
          (df_b.index.year == 2000)]
print (df)
                   var
datetime              
2000-01-01  165.792185
2000-01-02  166.066959
2000-10-15  114.232790
2000-10-16  113.020661
```

EDIT:

```
df = df_b[df_b.index.month.isin(df_a.index.month) & df_b.index.day.isin(df_a.index.day)]
print (df)
                   var
datetime              
2000-01-01  165.792185
2000-01-02  166.066959
2000-10-15  114.232790
2000-10-16  113.020661
2001-01-01  164.792185
2001-01-02  161.066959
2002-10-15  174.232790
2003-10-16  114.020661

#create dictionary of weights by factorize
a = pd.factorize(df_a.index.strftime('%m-%d'))
d = dict(zip(a[1], a[0]))
print (d)
{'01-02': 6, '10-19': 4, '10-18': 3, '10-15': 0, '01-01': 5, '10-16': 1, '10-17': 2}

#ordering Series, multiple by 1000 becasue possible 1 to 366 MMDD
order = pd.Series(df.index.strftime('%m-%d'), index=df.index).map(d) + df.index.year * 1000
print (order)
datetime
2000-01-01    2000005
2000-01-02    2000006
2000-10-15    2000000
2000-10-16    2000001
2001-01-01    2001005
2001-01-02    2001006
2002-10-15    2002000
2003-10-16    2003001
Name: datetime, dtype: int64
```

Last [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by sorted `order` index:

```
df = df.reindex(order.sort_values().index)
print (df)
                   var
datetime              
2000-10-15  114.232790
2000-10-16  113.020661
2000-01-01  165.792185
2000-01-02  166.066959
2001-01-01  164.792185
2001-01-02  161.066959
2002-10-15  174.232790
2003-10-16  114.020661
```

Comment: thanks @jezrael, however this messes up the order. i want month and day order to follow df_a

Comment: OK, so now I am a bit confused, do you need filter by `2000` year or multiple years like `2001, 2002..` ?

Comment: i want all years 2000, 2001 and 2002. the idea is not to filter for any year.  just want order of month and day in each of 2000, 2001, 2002.. to follow order of month and day in df_1

Comment: Please check edited answer. Solution working only id unique `MMDD` combination in `df_a`.